# Handling MySQL data in iPhone app

Tags: iphone, mysql, objective-c, ios, database

If I want to take data from a remote MySQL db and want to turn data into a custom objective-c object, can I do this by returning JSON or XML?

Currently I have XML flat-files which I parse using NSXMLParser, which allows me to create custom objects out of my data. Could I go through a similar process with my remote db by retrieving the data through a web-service with returns XML or JSON?

I have currently succeeded in obtaining a connection and retrieving a simple string stored in JSON, and then used JSONTouch to parse the array into an NSArray. Could I somehow modify that approach to parse larger amounts of data into objects?

Is this not a common issue among developers? I'll finally just broaden the question and ask how one typically goes about retrieving data from an external db and dealing with it in an iphone app?

Thanks